# How to monitor JVM memory?is there any tool avaiable other than JVisual VM, also have tried with jconsole but it is giving data only for one day

Tags: jvm, monitoring

is there any *tool* avaiable other than **JVisual VM**, also have tried with **jconsole** but it is giving data only for one day

Comment: yourkit can be useful as well

Answer (score 1):

Java Mission Control is pretty good and available for free in Java 7 above I believe.....for commercial one we're using DynaTrace, and it provides other detailed information in addition to JVM info.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic is another tool for constant application monitoring with a lot of out-of-the box options. Among others it allows to see history records (for hours, days, weeks, months) including memory, cpu, etc.